# Python class attribute name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to print my custom class

```
class Car():
    door = 4

print(type(Car.door))

----------
# output 
<class 'int'>
```

I tried to print other library package class.

```
print(type(somePackageclass.attributeName))

------
# output
<class 'api.feature.error'>
```

Why my custom class is different? It always show attribute type.
And what kind of information colud be got from above example `'api.feature.error'`

Comment: How is your class different? In both your examples the type/class of the attribute was printed, the attributes just have different types

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's not the attribute name that you're printing, but the type of an attribute

Comment: @IainShelvington why library show information like that? Could you give me tips how to do like that?

Comment: @bumbread is it custom data type?

Comment: Someone defined a package named `api` that contains a module named `feature` that contains a class named `error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `somepackageclass.attributeName` is a variable holding an object.
- `type(somepackageclass.attributeName)` is the type of that object
- `print(type(somepackageclass.attribute))` is the human friendly name of that type

Since the value's type is `<class 'api.feature.error'>`, it means that this object is an instance of the class `api.feature.error`.

You can see the same thing happening in your first example. `Car.door` is `4`. `type(4)` is its class: `int`. And printing its type is `<class int>`.

Both `int` and `api.feature.error` are classes - and classes are objects too. Its a bit of a mind bender, but classes are themselves instances of the class `type`. Since "class" is a keyword in python, it can't be the name of this special class. So, while `type(4)` is `<class int>`, `type(int)` is `<type int>` (an instance of `int` verses `int` iself).